# Is there a way to shortcut this long if/else if return method?

Tags: c#

I have this really long method:

```
public decimal decDiscount(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7499)
            return 5300;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7449)
            return 5300;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7399)
            return 5250;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7349)
            return 5200;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7299)
            return 5200;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7249)
            return 5150;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7199)
            return 5100;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7149)
            return 5100;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 7099)
            return 5050;
            //...
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 1199)
            return 1100;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 1149)
            return 1100;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 1099)
            return 1050;
        else if (TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= 1049)
            return 1000;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

which has a recurring pattern which can be illustrated by the following Excel sheet:

[image: Excel sheet part 1]
......>>>>
[image: Excel sheet part 2]

Starting from the highest "Fee" (7499), the fee is dropping 50 on each statement. However, the return (or "Discounted Price") stays the same for each 100 (two 50 drops in Fee), then drops 50 itself for one return (one 50 drop in Fee), and then repeats.

As you can see my method is pretty long (what I left out between 7049 and 1249). Is there something I can do to shorten this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just work it out using integer arithmetic. Start with `var row = Math.Floor ((TotalChapter7 (quoteData) + 1) / 50) ;`

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Sounds like it would work. Can you provide an example in an answer?

Comment: @Anton Tykhyy: That can't be right, it would get the piecewise constant nature of it right, but not the fact that some of the segments are longer than others.

Comment: The example would be the answer. Get a piece of paper and work it out. @Jason: that's a *start*, not the whole answer. Integer arithmetic is powerful enough to deal with different segment lengths, because they're regular.

Comment: @Anton Tykhyy: Well, frankly, any approach along these lines is a terrible idea because it will be really hard to understand and difficult to maintain if the pricing structure changes.

Comment: @Jason ***ANY*** solution will be hard to maintain if the pricing structure changes.

Comment: @Servy: No. Look, this pricing structure has a RULE that defines. The OP can spell it out in English in his post. Translate that to code. It's easier to discover, easier to write, easier to understand, and easier to maintain!

Comment: @Jason If the entire pricing structure changes then whatever pattern, rule, or values currently used become meaningless, because it's changed.

Comment: @Jason Yes, and the rule translated in code will look something like Jack's answer. Well maybe it would be better e.g. not to divide by 50 as I wrote above. Write the rule for clarity rather than speed, compilers and jitters are good at optimizing arithmetic.

Comment: @Anton Tykhyy: No, no, no the rule doesn't translate into that at all. A rule that said "start with 7500, divide it by 50 and add price + 1 over 50" blah blah blah would translate into what Jack said. Read the OP again. The pricing rule is there, in plain English. And how ironic that you say write for clarity, yet are insisting this difficult to understand formula is the way to go.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: A slightly modified binary search will make the lookup O(log N). Unless you can gaurantee a permanent fixed interval.

Comment: I really appreciate all the suggestions and debate. I get the "lazy" comments regarding programming. FYI, I am not a programmer. Please don't flame me with "then why are you programming?" questions. Consider it a hobby with real life implementations.

Comment: It's all right, I'm sure nobody here meant offense. There's just so many *programmers* ('programmers'?) who ask inane questions without trying a thing by themselves (see http://whathaveyoutried.com/), however, that people get a bit jumpy.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Yeah, I tried (see OP), and tried (see my "Recycle Bin"). :) Working a formula out on paper for me isn't too hard, it's the translation to code that gets me.

Comment: But you don't claim to be a programmer! :) Had you mentioned this fact at the beginning, people would have fallen over themselves to teach you. I, for one, wouldn't have written this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802613/is-there-a-way-to-shortcut-this-long-if-else-if-return-method#comment14055596_10802613.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guys are really overcomplicating this. Any approach along the lines of trying to solve this using integer arithmetic is a bad idea. Look how hard it is for a bunch of really smart people (we are all really smart, aren't we?) to even get it right in the first place. It's really hard to discover, it's really hard to understand, it's hard to get right, and it's a bitch to maintain.

You need an approach that is easy to understand, and easy to maintain. Look at your original post, you have an English description of the rule.

> However, the return (or "Discounted Price") stays the same for each 100 (two 50 drops in Fee), then drops 50 itself for one return (one 50 drop in Fee), and then repeats.

The code practically writes itself:

```
public int GetFeeFromQuoteData(QuoteData quoteData) {
    int fee = 5300;
    int difference = 7449 - TotalChapter7(quoteData);
    bool isTwoStep = true;

    while (difference > 0) {
        if (isTwoStep) {
            difference -= 50;
        }
        else {
            difference -= 100;
        }
        fee -= 50;
        isTwoStep = !isTwoStep;
    }
    return fee;
}
```

Comment: Speaking as someone who is not smart in C# (or much else -- BOOM!), I tried "writing this" myself with some simple arithmetic and realized there was a reason I became a lawyer. :) But I want to thank you ALL for your efforts, I am trying to fiddle around with some of the suggested answers to see which works.

Comment: @REMESQ: You don't need simple arithmetic. I have translated your English description of your pricing into code. It's correct, it's easy to understand, it's easy to change if you change your pricing rule.

Comment: I understand your idea, but is it really so much easier to understand and write (how many times have you edited it already?) than to think about the pricing structure and realize that the discounted fee drops 100 for each 150 drop in the original fee?

Comment: Yes, it is. There is a very clear connection from the English description to my code. And I don't see how a **minor** edit is at all relevant. The semantics of the code never changed.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and being the cause of what I may be under-exaggerating as "lively" debate, but this solution worked to the point of my requirements. Just editing to match my requirements, since the `price` threw me off for a second. Also, I am using decimals (not a big deal will leave as is).

Answer (score 2):

**These prices & discounts are *DATA*! Data should never be compiled into code**

I wouldn’t build the drops into the code, I’d build the underlying pricing structure (they may well play with the drops in the prices, but are less likely to change the overall pricing structure).

I’d have the prices & associated discounts in an easily changeable place(e.g. database, xml file) that reflects this structure.

```
public class Pricing
{
     private List<Tuple<decimal, decimal>> pricePoints= new List<Tuple<int, decimal>> discountRanges();

    public Pricing()
    {
        // These hard coded values would be replaced by logic to load from file.
        pricePoints.Add(Tuple.Create(7499, 5300));
        pricePoints.Add(Tuple.Create(7399, 5250));
        pricePoints.Add(Tuple.Create(7349, 5200));
        pricePoints.Add(Tuple.Create(7249, 5150));
        . . .
        pricePoints.Add(Tuple.Create(1049, 1000));
    }

    public decimal GetDiscount(QuoteData quoteData)
    {
        var price = TotalChapter7(quoteData);
        foreach(var point in pricePoints)
        {
            if(price >= point.Item1)
                return point.Item2;
        }
        // If we're here it implies there were no matching points
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you build the drops into the code, and they change the drops, you've to change the code.
Put the data in a file, load the file once at run time, and they can change the prices and you just need to change the file.

**Rebuttal to "This here is clearly a business rule" comment**

Excluding discounts at point of sale (2 for one offers, 10% off this item etc), there are basically three ways to calculate a discount on an overall charge or fee (any of which can be combined with a preferred customer discount).

- Flat percentage (e.g. 10% always)
- Different percentages for different price points.
- Different flat prices for different price points (which is what we see
  in the question)

Which one (or ones) the customer decides to use is a business rule and yes, the rule needs to be represented in the code.

However regardless of which rule is used, the actual values are data, and that data should **never** (barring *highly* exceptional circumstances) be in the code.

Comment: would the Down voter care to tell me why? If there's something wrong with my answer I'd like to know, we're all here to learn after all :)

Comment: *Data should never be compiled into code* — only a Sith deals in absolutes. Business rules are a well-known gray area, witness the XML rule engines, stored DB procedures etc.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: Eh... He's right; 99% of the time, this should be data, not code.  Are you going to ding him for the 1% where that's not the case?

Comment: I haven't dinged (-1'ed) him. The 'data vs code' distinction is overrated. This here is clearly a business rule. It's more liable to change and closer to the real world than UI or database-access code, but it's not a table of products or website text either. For bonus points, consider XAML. Is it data or code?

Comment: Not to get into a lengthy discussion about it, but XAML is more accessible than C#, and it can be manipulated with external, XML-based tools.  XAML is not Turing-complete, AFAIK.  It's a DSL, basically.

Comment: Who cares?  Making that pedantic distinction won't help you use it better.  The pros and cons must be evaluated on their own merits.  As I said, XAML is not Turing-complete, AFAIK.  Are Lisp s-expressions data or code?

Comment: LOL. Those who push the 'data vs code' would seem to care, no? As for XAML, it's not very easy to manipulate with XML tools (if one wants to have working XAML output, that is). And manipulating C#/VB source has become easier with Roslyn. **Added:** I was going to mention Lisp but you did it first. Thanks for supporting my argument against data-vs-code distinction!

Comment: @Anton: I've updated my answer, do you still think it's _Sithy_?

Comment: @Robert: XAML is still code, you've still to recompile, redeploy. I don't see how it helps the "Data v's code" debate, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes. ~150 price points stretch the *Different flat prices for different price points* case quite a bit, IMHO.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: not necessarily. XAML can be loaded at runtime from a stream just fine, it's just not done very often.

Comment: @Anton: I've implemented POS systems on sites with 10's of thousands of different price- and quantity-break discounts. The levels and prices were regularly tweaked to a) appear competitive and b) confuse customers. I'd mention a large Electronics Wholesaler in Dublin as a case in point . . . except I can't for obvious reasons. 
P.s. I stand corrected on XAML so :)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Is 150 price points in a single discount a regular occurrence? Just wondering.

Comment: @Anton: It's been a while (I left that company in 1999), but it was a regular occurrence in wholesalers, most of the sites we had back in the day sold autoparts (spare parts for cars), those guys were crazy competitive and generally, just crazy. But yes, I've seen worse.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

```
        List<Tuple<int, int>> _FeeToPrice = new List<Tuple<int, int>> { 
                new Tuple<int,int>(7499,5300),
                new Tuple<int,int>(7399,5250),
                            ...
                new Tuple<int,int>(1049,1000)
            };

        public decimal decDiscount(QuoteData quoteData)
        {
            var processedQuoteData = TotalChapter7(quoteData);
            var tuple = _FeeToPrice.FirstOrDefault(x => processedQuoteData >= x.Item1);
            if (tuple != null)
                return tuple.Item2;

            return 0;                           
        }
```

Edit:
`_FeeToPrice` structure could be loaded from file or database or some other source, which would allow easier corrections of the returned value

Comment: Why bothering with a large data structure when some hand and paper can solve the formula in an analytic way? See my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Working formula, calculated analytically is the following:

```
int calcDiscount(int p)
{
  int s = (7500/50) - (p+1) / 50;
  int k = s / 3;
  int j = s % 3;

  return 5300 - 100*k - (j == 2 ? 50 : 0) 
}
```

Working testcase (in Java):

```
for (p = 7499; p >= 1000; p -= 50)
{
  System.out.println (p+ " " + calcDiscount(p));
}
```

Explanation: first you find how many drop steps from maximum (7499) are for the current price, then you know you must drop discounted value by 100 every three steps, but if you are on last step of current triplet you must drop it by an additional 50.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Good luck maintaining it if the pricing structure changes slightly.

Comment: Yep, but OP would be better off if he'd worked it out himself. IMHO.

Comment: @Jason It would be easier to maintain a giant table of every single value when the formula (or start/end range) changes?

Comment: @Jason: I don't see it being terrible, copy and pasting hundreds of lines of predefined pairs is more expensive than recalculating a similar formula.

Comment: @Jack: Straw man. I didn't say the alternative that the OP presented is a good solution either.

Comment: @Jason what's a better alternative then? The pricing structure still has to be defined somewhere and that somewhere has to be changed if it changes. Does not matter very much if it's a piece of code or a dictionary or an XML file.

Comment: @Jason according to your opinion, every piece of code that needs a little bit of thinking is expensive to maintain. Probably is a matter of taste, I find managing a big list much more boring and expensive, while finding an analytical formula much more funny and satisfying.

Comment: @Jack: Your assessment of my opinion is utterly wrong, and doesn't follow from anything I've said.

Comment: "Does not matter very much if it's a piece of code or a dictionary or an XML file" Really? You've never worked in a company with a Q/A or "Change management" department have you? Getting data changes tested & passed is a minor task compared to the most trivial of code changes. **These prices are data and data should never be compiled into code.**

Comment: @Jack I feel your pain. Sometimes one has to make allowances for the fact that lots of developers don't seem to think at all, though. I know *I* should think more often...

Comment: @Jason do you realize that a slight change in the formula would be reflected with a slight change in my code while you could need to rewrite all the lines of a table based approach?

Comment: @Jack: You and that table-based approach. I never said it was the right way. You're attacking a straw man. Again, **there is an English description of the pricing rule** in the original post. That English description is what should be translated into code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10803086/45914

Comment: @Jason my implementation is tightly coupled onto his description. The fact that you approached the problem iteratively instead that by calculating the correct step at once it's just a your choice that __has nothing to do__ with a better/more correct solution. The rules used are __exactly the same__ in my and your solution.

Comment: @Jack: Well, I'd sure hope the rules are the same. I didn't say your answer is wrong. I said your answer is difficult to understand (meaning, it's difficult to see a clear connection from the English description of the rule to the code) and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code below:

```
Dictionary<Int, Int> getDiscounts(int startFee, int startDiscount, int endFee)
{
    Dictionary <Int, Int> quoteDictionary = new Dictionary<Int, Int> ();
    for(int i = 0; i++; startFee >= endFee)
    {
         startFee -= 50;
         if(i != 0)
         {
             startDiscount -= 50;
         }
         if(i == 2)
         {
             i = -1;
         }
         quoteDictionary[startFee] = startDiscount;
    }
    return quoteDictionary;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Dictionary <Int, Int> prices = getDiscounts(7499, 5300, 1049);
int quote = TotalChapter7(quoteData);
int roundedQuote = quote - ((quote % 50) + 1);
int discountedFee = prices[roundedQuote];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but you could use a dictionary, and sort on the key in descending order as in your example above.

I haven't tested it, but something like this might work:

```
public int GetNumber(int value)
{
    //initialize a dictionary to hold pairs of numbers
    var ranges = new SortedDictionary<int, int>
    {
        { 25, 250 },
        { 50, 500 },
        { 75, 750 }
    };

    //sort the dictionary in descending order and return the first value
    //that satisfies the condition
    return ranges.OrderByDescending(p => p.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => value >= p.Key).Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using a dictionary, tried to make an example, but I don't use C# to often, so correct whatever is not right on the code, just try to get the idea:

```
public decimal decDiscount(QuoteData quoteData)
{
    int result = 0; //if it doesn't match to any value on the dictionary it will return 0
    Dictionary<int, int> quotes = new Dictionary<int, int();
    quotes.add(7499, 5300); // not sure if that's how you add values to a dictionary
    ...
    quotes.add(1049, 1000);

    for(Entry<int, int> element in quotes) //not sure about the enhanced for too hehehe, not using C# for a while
    {
        if(TotalChapter7(quoteData) >= element.key() && element.value > result)
        {
            result = element.value(); //don't break cause you have to test the entire list for acurracy
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you'll still have a long dictionary, but you'll save some line of if/else hehehehe, plus if you can order the dictionary in decreasing order you can break the loop on the first match.

Comment: can someone explain the down vote? whats wrong with the answer?

Comment: The Dictionary values will be unordered.  If you used a `SortedDictionary` (or just a LINQ OrderBy call) then you could ensure the values were iterated in the proper order.

Comment: I know that the dictionary is unordered, that's why I didn't break on the if, this way it will check for all the values, I would only break if the dictionary was ordered, check the code carefully.

Comment: Your code will return the value of one arbitrary key that's smaller than your quote.  You need to return the largest key that's smaller than the quote, not just any one.